# Why in CSS: first letter, text-transform: uppercase; doesn't work?

Tags: css

In this case I want to make the first letter of the word "things" `uppercase`, but something went wrong. Where is my fault?

```css
.things:first-letter{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="some-things">Some <span class="things">things</span></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `::first-letter` [only works on block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> [...] applies styles to the first letter of the first line of **a block-level element** [...]

`<span>`s [are not block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span):

> [...] a <span> is an inline element.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```css
.things {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p class="some-things">Some <span class="things">things are working now</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, but looks like `:first-letter` only works on block level elements

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.things:first-letter{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="some-things">Some <span class="things">things</span></p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first
>   letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not
>   preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `capitalize` value insted of selector ::frist-letter

Like this:

```css
.things {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

In order to make the first letter uppercase.